# summing up the values of particular range of second column in a data file

Tags: python

I have data file consisting of two columns, first column values range from -360 to 720 and second column consists of values for these.

I am trying to write a python code such that for a given value of first column, it should take the corresponding value of it and add up above 30 to below 30 values of second column.For eg, data file consists of

```
.......
.......
-40 2.2
.......
.......
0   1.14
........
........
60  5.12
........
```

If a value of 20 is given then it should add the values of the second column starting from -10 to 50 i.e.,range for second column should be (20-30,20+30) I have tried it by taking each line as list in other list,but it's not working.

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect to happen with negative lines numbers? Should it wrap around to the end of the file?

Comment: Can you show your code that's not working?

Comment: so 20 in col1 (always int?), and col2 (could be float?) has 50. *Replace* value in col 1 with the sum of values in the range 50-30 to 50+30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not clear as many commentators noticed.

I would use dictionary with 1st column as key and 2nd as value. Then for given key (`starting point`) I would sum up values from that dictionary with keys in given range (`diff)`.

```
VALUES = {-4: 0.1, -3: 0.2, -2: 0.3, -1: 0.4,
    0: 0.5, 1: 0.6, 2: 0.7, 3:  0.8, 4: 0.9}

def sum_part(start_point, diff):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(start_point - diff, start_point + diff + 1):
        try:
            sum += VALUES[i]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        #print('%d: %.2f' % (i, sum))
    return sum

def test_sum(start_point, diff):
    sum = sum_part(start_point, diff)
    print('sum(%d, %d): %.2f' % (start_point, diff, sum))

test_sum(1, 3)
```

Assumption: non existing keys are counted as 0. Uncomment `print()` to see if keys and sum are correct. If you want to sum up only existing keys then you will have to go from starting point in both directions and sum until `diff` values from each side is summed. As wooble commented show us your code.

Comment: I think the value in the 2nd column can be a float in which case range won't work, no?

Comment: Thank you for ur reply and sorry for not posing the question properly.Actually it is a part of the code i am writing.let me explain u in other way around taking simple example, data file consisting of two columns and if values in first column are -4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4 and if 2nd column has 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9.If input is given as 1(value corresponding to 1st column) then(taking value 3 rather than 20 as posted earlier)output should be 0.4+0.5+0.6+0.7+0.8 (sum of the values of 2nd column corresponding to 1st column values from -1 to 3,i.e range for 1st column will be (1-3,1+3))

Comment: @Levon as u have pointed out second column values are float but the range specified is for the first column which are integers.

Comment: @Michał Niklas thanks alot for ur reply.the way u have suggested usage of dictionary,do i need to store all the values of the dictionary in a list.If so then the values[i] will not correspond to the range I need.Can u please explain me in detail.Thanks in advance

Comment: See my example code. Dictionary has `keys()` and `values()`. In dictionary "constructor" we use `{key1: value1, key2: value2}`. Then `keys()` is a list with `[key1, key2]` and values is a list with `[value1, value2]`. I do not use those list in this example. Keys are typically strings but can be other types too and here I used integers.

Comment: @Michał Niklas thanks, thanks alot for ur help i am trying to implement the way u have suggested in my code.i will get back to u soon.